# Firefox - disable specific JavaScript library on the page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

In Chrome, there is a feature called [Blackboxing](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/blackboxing). Actually they implemented it after Firefox introduced it. It basically allows you to debug your code without stepping into library codes which is super handy. But in Chrome you also have the option to `disable` a specific JS file.

Is there such a thing in Firefox?

Comment: why not manually remove and check that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Firefox, you can also use AdBlock Plus to block all functions in a specific file. (Instructions below are for Windows.)

In the toolbar, click the AdBlock Plus icon, and select Open blockable items from the menu.
A window will appear, listing everything that ABP can block. You can scroll through the list to find the particular script file or you can type in the Search box to narrow the list down. Once you've found the file to block, right-click the file and select Block this item .
ABP will create a new filter based on that file and will list several options for you:

The complete path to the file
([complete path](http://www.example.com/scripts/ascriptyoudontwanttoinclude.js))

Any file in that subdomain

(www.example.com)

Any file in that domain
A custom rule that you can define; by default, this starts off the same as 1.
Click the radio button next to the first option and click Add filter. This will close the window and add that JavaScript file to the list of blocked items.
You may need to refresh the page to ensure that file is blocked.

Comment: in chrome the process is same!